# Vertical align contents of 2 side-by-side auto-width DIVs

Tags: css, html

I've tried various combinations of html elements and CSS to get this to work to no avail. How do I accomplish the following?

I have two DIVs side-by-side which I want to size automatically according to the width of their contents (was using "display: inline-block" for that). Then, I want the contents of each of those DIVs aligned to the top of the DIV (by default, the contents are bottom-aligned). The contents are a number of labels (spans) and text (database data). Also, these two DIVs should stay to the right of another DIV on the left of the page which is the menu.

```
MENU      AUTO            ANOTHER
FIXED     WIDTH           COLUMN (DIV)
WIDTH     DIV             ALSO
DIV       ACCORDING       AUTO
          TO              SIZED
          CONTENTS        TOP-ALIGNED
          TOP-ALIGNED     CONTENTS
          CONTENTS        SOME
          SOME            PADDING
          PADDING TO      TO MY LEFT
          MY LEFT AND     AND RIGHT
          RIGHT
```

Comment: Not sure why the site wouldn't give me a toolbar for fixing my goof, but looks like someone else was able to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle, or post some code?

Comment: You beat me.. I was almost done editing it :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to `vertical-align:top` the parent (column) div, as well as the `span`s on the inside.  `display:inline-block` makes width and height go to auto (like an inline element), and as you said default vertical align is baseline.

http://jsfiddle.net/EjdUf/1/

Comment: I have been reading that vertical-align is for inline elements, not block level elements, but I'll try this.

Comment: Huh, unless I didn't understand what I read, this doesn't seem right, BUT it also seems to work! Thanks!

Comment: `display:inline-block` allows you to have the positioning of an inline element, but also the ability to set things like margin, padding, width, etc, that are only for block level.  Just be careful if this is intended for IE, as there are issues with support of the inline-block value for IE8 and below (maybe just ie7 and below)